# Can UPPAAL get all the counterexamples?

Tags: uppaal

When I enter `A[] not Automata.locationA` in the validation screen for reachability analysis, I can get a symbolic trace (counterexample) when the model doesn't satisfy the property, sometimes there is more than one counterexample, is there a way for me to get all similar counterexamples?
Here "Automata" means template and "locationA" means a specified location.

I want to know if UPPAAL can get all the counterexamples (symbolic traces), and if so, how do I get it?

Comment: Currently there is no automatic way

Comment: @mariusm hello, how do you achieve this manually if you can't automate it?